# Java Rx Observable method switchIfEmpty

Tags: java, rx-java

**RxJava Lib** 
Method **switchIfEmpty** 
the instructions inside, are always executed.
Then will be evalutate if the observable is empty or not and the source or alternative will be returned. 
Is there a method that allows to pass just a supplier of observable that will be execute only if the source observable is empty?

As an java Optional is the same difference between

- Optional.orElse()
- Optional.orElseGet()

//get number from cache

```
private Observable<Integer> getNFromCache(){

return Observable.empty;
    }


public Observable<Integer> getNumber(){

        return getNFromCache(scope)
        .switchIfEmpty(this::doHttpRequest);

    }


private Observable<Integer> doHttoRequest(){

    return Observable.of(1);

 }
```

My solution

```
      //try to get number from cache  
public Observable<Integer> getNFromCache(){ 
    return Observable.empty;
}


private Observable<Integer> getNumber(){

 Observable<Integer> result= getNFromCache(scope);
 return !result.isEmpty().blocking().first()?result:
 result.switchIfEmpty(this::doHttpRequest);

            }


public Observable<Integer> doHttoRequest(){

   return Observable.of(1);

}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There is a method that allows to pass just a supplier of observable that will be execute only if the source observable is empty?

An `Observable` can be see as a Supplier : it will generate your values later (ie: when you'll subscribe)

Even if the `switchIfEmpty` is called when you call your `getNumber` method, the `Observable` given as an argument to `switchIfEmpty` will only emit if you `subscribe` to your `Observable`

So, by nature, this observable will only be executed only if the source observable is empty

```
private Observable<Integer> getNFromCache(){
    return Observable.empty;
}


public Observable<Integer> getNumber(){
      return getNFromCache(scope)
              .switchIfEmpty(this::doHttpRequest);
}


private Observable<Integer> doHttpRequest(){
    return Observable.of(1)
                     .doOnSubscribe(() -> System.out.pritnln("START !"))
}

public static void main(String...args) {
   getNumber(); // display nothing => values are not emitted !
   getNumber().subscribe(); // display "START !"
}
```

Comment: Instead of just printing, I want to replace the placeholding `Observable.of(1)` with another observable that emits real values, since I can't return anything in `doOnSubscribe`, how do I do this?